# como convertir de VARCHAR a DATATIME en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

En mi tabla registro, tengo una columna llamada fecha, pero he importado datos(15000 datos) y al momento de guardar se ha guardado asi:

01/01/2018 0:09:07    --> pero en tipo VARCHAR(100)

quisiera saber como puedo modificar esa columna y convertir a DATATIME

Comment: Hola, cuando tienes fechas guardadas en _varchar_ si estas estan en formato _yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss_ solo vasta con hacer un update: `ALTER TABLE tabla
MODIFY COLUMN fecha  datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL;`, en tu caso antes deberás cambiar el formato de tus fechas o se verán como _0000-00-00 00:00:00_,  ¿estas empleando algún lenguaje como php?

Comment: @the-breaker como cambio el formato de mis fechas para que no se vean 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ... si estoy trabajando con codigo php pero en este caso no implica creo...o si?

Comment: podrías hacer una rutina php que realice el update de tus fechas cambiándoles el formato, es mejor a buscar una solución solo en mysql que existe pero es bastante complicada

Comment: yo quiero cambiar el formato de tipo de valor de la columna, para que cuando ingresen nuevos valores se guarden como datatime y no como un string

Comment: ¿no importa si se pierden los valores anteriores? si es el caso con `ALTER TABLE tabla MODIFY COLUMN fecha datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL;`es mas que suficiente

Comment: si, importa los valores anteriores, el detalle es que esos valores los importe de excel, pero lo pase a un formato *.csv y no me reconocia los valores de la fecha de mi excel, entonces por eso al momento de crear mi tabla de mysql creee con VARCHAR  a todos los valores para que reconosca a todo como texto

Comment: mucho mejor, entonces podrías modificar las fechas en el excel; abre el excel, has click derecho en la parte superior de la columna de fechas y selecciona _Formato de celdas..._, en _Categoría_ pon _Personalizada_ y luego pon en tipo _yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss_ y ya tendrás el formato que necesitas.